# How to prevent android from killing whole app

Tags: android, kotlin

My app has 3 activities:
-PreloaderActivity
-SelectorActivity(main screen)
-GameActivity

Preloader activity does some initialization work and fills singleton `AppData` structure:

```
class AppData(val locale:String,                           //device locale
              val online: Boolean,                         // do we online?
              val onSDCard:Boolean,                        //do we on sdcard?
              val idfa:String?,                            //id for advertising
              val isTablet:Boolean,                        //tablet or phone
              var awardsTimestamp:Long=-1,                 //tasks.json last modification time
              var gdprStatus:ConsentStatus?=null,
              val inapData: InapManager.InapData?,         //google play inap data
              val version:Version                          //app version

) {
    companion object{
        lateinit var instance:AppData
            private set
        private var reseted=false
        val isInitialized:Boolean
            get()=(::instance.isInitialized && !reseted)
        fun dispose() {
            reseted=true
        }
    }
    init {
        //singleton instantiation
        if(!isInitialized) {
            reseted=false
            instance = this
        }
    }
```

After initialization app goes to `SelectorActivity` and then to `GameActivity`. The problem is when something breaks on the game screen android kills whole app and tries to restore selector activity.But it can't be restored as `AppData` singleton is NOT initialized now.Is there way to make android to not kill selector activity?

Comment: Isn't the solution to stop it breaking in the first place? If you want to persist state after an app's process has died then you need some sort of persistence mechanism like `SharedPreferences`

Comment: The key problem is after app proccess died I receive only `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property instance has not been initialized` without any data about initial exception